# How to create resource ref for a JBoss MBean

Tags: java, jboss, jndi, jmx

A have an application deployed to JBoss. It contains inside it I register Quartz MBean which triggers a scheduled task.

How can I create resource ref for that MBean to access resource by `java:/comp/env/*` and not `java:/*` in my task code?

Answer (score 0):

In a web app, add something like the following to web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>QuartzObject</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>class.of.quartz.object</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

and add something like the following to jboss-web.xml:

```
<resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>QuartzObject</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>class.of.quartz.object</res-type>
  <jndi-name>jndi/name/bound/by/mbean</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
```

with that in place, you should be able to lookup the resource using the local resource reference, `java:comp/env/QuartzObject`.